# Como saber para hacer una comparacion, cuantas filas he devuelto

Tags: mysql, sql

Mi pregunta es que tengo una base de datos de la siguiente manera

```
ID_CASA   ID_COMPOSICION
11        25
11        28
11        30
12        25
13        28
13        30
```

Quiero que eligiendo yo el parametro que le voy a meter, que me indique el numero de componentes tiene la casa, me salga  si los cumple, por ejemplo
si meto como parametro `idcomposiciones =2` quiero que me devuelva

```
ID_CASA   ID_COMPOSICION
13        28
13        30
```

yo habia pensado algo de esta forma pero no funciona:

```
group by id_casa, id_composicion
having count(*) = idcomposiciones
```

¿Alguna idea? Necesito tipo un contador de filas y comparar con lo que me devuelva el contador de filas.

Comment: El count (*) va en la sentencia SELECT , y te devolvera el numero de filas de la consulta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

en este caso, creo que lo que necesitas es una subconsulta.

he supuesto lo siguiente: he llamado a mi tabla ejemplo, y para utilizarla he metido los valores que tienes:

```
create table ejemplo ( id_casa int not null, id_composicion int not_null);
insert into ejemplo(id_casa, id_composicion) VALUES
(11,25),
(11,28),
(11,30),
(12,25),
(13, 28),
(13,30);
```

La consulta que puedes hacer es:

```
select id_casa, id_composicion
from ejemplo
where id_casa in (
   select id_casa
   from ejemplo
   group by id_casa having count(id_composicion) = 3
);
```

Esto es: seleccionas en la tabla ejemplo aquellos ids que necesitas de id_casa, que esten en un listado, que esta agrupado por id_casa (el campo agrupador) y un having que filtra los que la funcion de agrupamiento count (en este caso sobre los campos diferentes del agrupador) cumplen que sean iguales a un numero (en mi ejemplo, el 3)

con el 3, te sale:

```
id_casa id_composicion
11  25
11  28
11  30
```

en caso de 2:

```
id_casa id_composicion
13  28
13  30
```

para el 1:

```
id_casa id_composicion
12  25
```